# How does a test-framework like Mocha run tests without a runner like Karma?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-mocha

From what I understand about testing in Javascript, **test runners** like Karma are used to *run* the tests written in **test frameworks** like Mocha.
Now, my question is, how do tests execute when I input a command like `mocha` in my npm project without having Karma?

Is my understanding of these testing terms faulty or is there something that I am missing here?

Note: I have read that Karma is used to run tests on various browsers as well as various devices. But then how is Mocha different from it? Is it just that Mocha's output is on the terminal while Karma outputs on the browser??

Comment: My understanding of testing terms comes from this article: https://amzotti.github.io/testing/2015/03/16/what-is-the-difference-between-a-test-runner-testing-framework-assertion-library-and-a-testing-plugin/

Comment: Bear in mind that Mocha supports Node.js _and_ browsers. Please specify which one you mean as the answer will significantly differ.

Comment: I mean in Node.js. But if it differs significantly, can you tell me how?